# Open source twain library

Tags: c#, wpf

Can you advice me open source twain library for scannning with pure good API.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Saraff Twain](https://sarafftwain.codeplex.com)

Project is active and has a few nice examples. I implemented it in a few minutes

UPDATE: The project moved to [github](https://github.com/saraff-9EB1047A4BEB4cef8506B29BA325BD5A/Saraff.Twain.NET)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's simple, well documented and uptodate noget package.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TWAIN sample Data Source and Application](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/). Although written in C++, you can use the supplied DLLs in your .NET application.

Also, I'd recommend reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx) on TWAIN image acquisition in C#.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 64bit I got an error (Twain device list always empty). I have found "TwainDotNet" https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet . 
Then I modified the well-documented testApp and worked like a charm...
Added to my project:

```
using TwainDotNet;
using TwainDotNet.TwainNative;
using TwainDotNet.WinFroms;
```

Files needed:

```
TwainDotNet.WinFroms.dll
TwainDotNet.dll
log4net.dll
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is another opensource TWAIN .Net implementation here:

http://opentwain.codeplex.com/